# Cordova/Phonegap: unable to access window.plugins

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to use the Cordova plugin **[SpeechRecognizer](https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer)**. Installing the plugin via `cordova plugin add https://github.com/poiuytrez/SpeechRecognizer` worked well under **Cordova 3.5.0**. However, I am now unable to access the plugin from within my application.

When I run `console.log(window);` after the app has been loaded on my virtual device I can see that it contains an object called `plugins`. And when I type `window.plugins.speechrecognizer` into the console I get:

> SpeechRecognizer {startRecognize: function, getSupportedLanguages: function}

But when I try to access the same object in my code through, for example, `console.log(window.plugins.speechrecognizer);` I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'speechrecognizer' of
>   undefined

My entire body looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(window);
    console.log(window.plugins.speechrecognizer);
</script>
```

I am using a 4.4.2 Android Virtual Device and Chrome 35.0 for debugging.

Comment: You usually need to wait until the deviceloaded event has fired for Cordova-related functionality to work.

Comment: When I am inspecting `window` **before** trying to access `window.plugins` I can see that it does have have an attribute `plugins`. Also, I get the same TypeError when I try to execute the function at run-time (after adding an event listener). So deviceloaded doesn’t seem to be the issue here.